# Is it possible to have zero or negative reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation

If someone started out with 1 reputation, answered a question, and that question got downvoted, would their reputation be -1, 0 or just 1?

Comment: This happens all the time. No, it's not possible.

Comment: I have seen people use this when they loose all their reputation by unaccepting and accepting all the answers to their questions, giving them +2 rep per question back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible to have zero or negative reputation?

No. That is not possible. 1 is the minimum.

> If someone started out with 1 reputation, answered a question, and that question got downvoted, would their reputation be -1, 0 or just 1?

1